# Get nodes sorted by proximity and at the same level sort by date

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm pretty new in neo4j and I have troubles to get a well result for my query. I have the next model:

```
Player <- HAS_PLAYERS - Game

Node Player: playerId, name,...etc
Node Game: gameId, gameDate
Rel. HAS_PLAYERS: result
```

Note that a Game could have 1-4 players.

I would like to make a query to suggest future opponents to a player ordered by:
Previous opponents ordered by `gameDate` (more recent) and then opponents of opponents ordered by `gameDate`.

For example:

```
PlayerA <- 2021/02/01 -> PlayerB*
PlayerA <- 2021/02/01 -> PlayerC*
PlayerA <- 2021/02/11 -> PlayerB

PlayerB <- 2021/02/04 -> PlayerC
PlayerB <- 2021/02/20 -> PlayerD

PlayerC <- 2021/02/15 -> PlayerD
PlayerC <- 2021/12/01 -> PlayerE

PlayerD <- 2021/02/07 -> PlayerE
PlayerD <- 2021/02/23 -> PlayerF

* = Same game

The result would be:

PlayerB
PlayerC
PlayerE
PlayerD
```

Explanation:
`PlayerB` and `PlayerC` have been opponents before but `PlayerB` is the first one because the last game was more recent than `PlayerC`.

`PlayerE` and `PlayerD` are opponents-of-opponents and `PlayerE` is before because the next game will be in December.

I have the next query but my problem is the query returns *duplicated nodes*:

```
# Getting direct opponents
MATCH (p:Player {userId: "PlayerA"})<-[:HAS_PLAYERS]-(g:Game)-[:HAS_PLAYERS]->(o:Player)
WITH p, o, g ORDER BY g.gameDate DESC 
WITH p, COLLECT(o) AS opponents
# Getting opponents-of-opponents (ops)
MATCH (p)-[:HAS_PLAYERS*3]-(gops:Game)--(ops:Player)
WHERE p.userId <> ops.userId AND NOT ops IN opponents
# Trying to remove duplicated nodes
WITH DISTINCT ops, opponents, gops
WITH opponents, ops, gops ORDER BY gops.gameDate DESC
# Concat both lists: opponents and opponents-of-opponents
WITH REDUCE(s = opponents, o2 IN COLLECT(ops) | s + o2) as listAllOpponents
UNWIND listAllOpponents as opPlayer
RETURN opPlayer
```

It returns something like:

```
PlayerB
PlayerC
PlayerD
PlayerE
PlayerD
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can playerA have the same game with Player B and Player C? Do you mean same game date instead of same game?  And who is this player ID: 34618?

Comment: The games have from 1 to 4 players. It's a system offline-online and some players are not added to the database. The player with ID: 34618 is the PlayerA. I preferred to use codenames instead of the id to make the question simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
# Getting direct opponents
MATCH (p:Player {userId: "PlayerA"})<-[:HAS_PLAYERS]-(g:Game)-[:HAS_PLAYERS]->(o:Player)
WITH p, o, max(g.gameDate) as maxDate
WITH p, o ORDER BY maxDate DESC
WITH p, COLLECT(o) AS opponents
# Getting opponents-of-opponents (ops)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_PLAYERS*3]-(gops:Game)--(ops:Player)
WHERE p.userId <> ops.userId AND NOT ops IN opponents
WITH opponents, ops, max(gops.start) as maxDate
WITH opponents, ops ORDER BY maxDate DESC
WITH opponents, COLLECT(ops) AS opponentsOfOpponents
# Concat both lists: opponents and opponents-of-opponents
UNWIND (opponents + opponentsOfOpponents) AS player
RETURN player
```

Answer (score 1):

When you aggregate the nodes, it will not remove duplicates so adding the keyword "distinct" will fix it.  Instead of COLLECT(o), use COLLECT(DISTINCT o) as opponents and COLLECT(DISTINCT ops).

```
// Getting direct opponents
MATCH (p:Player {userId: "34618"})<-[:HAS_PLAYERS]-(g:Game)-[:HAS_PLAYERS]->(o:Player)
WITH p, o, g ORDER BY g.gameDate DESC 
WITH p, COLLECT(DISTINCT o) AS opponents
// Getting opponents-of-opponents (ops)
MATCH (p)-[:HAS_PLAYERS*3]-(gops:Game)--(ops:Player)
WHERE p.userId <> ops.userId AND NOT ops IN opponents
// Trying to remove duplicated nodes
WITH DISTINCT ops, opponents, gops
WITH opponents, ops, gops ORDER BY gops.gameDate DESC
// Concat both lists: opponents and opponents-of-opponents
WITH REDUCE(s = opponents, o2 IN COLLECT(DISTINCT ops) | s + o2) as listAllOpponents
UNWIND listAllOpponents as opPlayer
RETURN opPlayer

Result:
   PlayerB
   PlayerC
   PlayerE
   PlayerD
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave a good clue and I could resolve it for myself.